# how can i open a fragment from gridview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i want to open a fragment from MainActivity where i have gridview.i am new to android and this is the first time to use fragment.
this is my mainactivity:

```
package com.example.grasu.petrosani;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    private DrawerLayout DrawerLayout;
    private NavigationView Drawer;
GridView gridview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Drawer = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        Drawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());



      gridview=findViewById(R.id.album_Gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(this));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (parent.getId()==R.id.album_Gridview){
            switch (position) {
                case 0:

            }
            }
        }
    }

this is my xml for activity main:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/album_Gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    </GridView>

</FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is the fragment i want to open from gridview:

```
package com.example.grasu.petrosani;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }}
```

i tried with FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                 ft.replace(CurrentClass.this, MainActivity.class); but it didn't work.do I have to modify my mainactivity to extend fragmentActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like -

- Create a New Activity.
- Add your Fragment in the above created Activity.
- In your GridView Item click, open the New Activity via an Intent like - `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class));`

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code:

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
    Fragment profileFragment = new InfoFragment();//the fragment you want to show
    profileFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, profileFragment);//R.id.content_frame is the layout you want to replace
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: I have a " cannot resolve symbol" error on bundle and in fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.album_Gridview,profileFragment) says : wrong 2nd argument type